# How to check if cp has completed before moving on to next item

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a bash that copies a large data file. How can I check that the file has completed copying before my bash script progresses?

```
 cp result.jtl $SCRIPT_DIR/FinalResult.jtl

#Next Bash step after FinalResult.jtl file has completed copying
echo "results file has completed copying"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you run the `cp` as a background job, it has to finish before anything else in the script happens.

You run commands in the background by adding `&` at the end of it.

Comment: @ viraptor. I think you might have solved my problem. My code double ampersands from a sed statement to a cp statement. Therefore I think the cp statement occurs in the background and therefore my script progresses even though the cp statement hasn't completed:

Comment: @user1654528 no, that is completely wrong. A single ampersand is the "put the preceding command in the background" operator. A double ampersand is the "if the preceding command succeeded execute the next command" operator. `sed 's/x/y' && cp foo bar` as you describe will NOT by itself execute the `cp` in the background.

Comment: But `sed` will not tell you whether a pattern matched; it will report success if it could parse your script and open the input file(s).